# Why cant I run script commands after an executable is called in a .sh file?

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts

I have tried googling my way through this but can't seem to find an answer.
In my .sh file I call an executable (which works fine) but it seems to block the rest of the script. I know you can run scripts from the terminal as background but I don't know how to run the executable asynchronously. 
Can someone point me in the right direction as I am new to shell scripting?
And thank you in advance for any input.

```
if [ -d "/usr/lib/kega-fusion" ];
then
    echo "Directory /usr/lib/kega-fusion exists " ;

    if [ -d "/usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs"];
    then 
        >> /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs/log.sh && echo `logging successful discovery of directory at $date`
        cd /usr/lib/kega-fusion/ && ./Fusion
    else
        echo "making logs directory"
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS mkdir -p /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs
        echo "Creating log.sh"
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS touch /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs/log.sh
        echo "Updating permissions"
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS chmod  755 /usr/lib/kega-fusion/;
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS chmod  755 /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs/;
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS chmod  722 /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs/log.sh;
        echo "Appending new log date"
        echo 'supass' | sudo -kS >> /usr/lib/kega-fusion/logs/log.sh && echo `logging successful discovery of directory at $date`

        cd /usr/lib/kega-fusion/ && ./Fusion && echo "why doesnt this line run?"
        WID = `xdotool search "Fusion 3.63x"`
        echo $WID
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any command or process you execute with an '&' symbol at the end of the line gets sent to the background, allowing your script to continue on to its next step while the process you appended the '&' to continues to do its own thing in the background.

For example, when executed in a shell script, this causes the line with the sleep timer to appear AFTER the line directly below it.  Because it has the '&' at the end of the line, it is sent off on its own to continue running while the script continues going down the line doing other things.  5 seconds after it runs the last line, the "echo" command I have on the second line pops up.

`echo "This is a test"
sleep 5 && echo "This is a test of the sleep functionality" &
echo "This should appear before the sleep test"`

So anyway, add an '&' to anything you want to run in the background while the script continues doing its own thing.  You may even want to redirect the output of those commands to a custom text/log file somewhere so its output doesn't overwhelm the terminal you're interacting with, but you still have a way to check for problems.  i.e.

`somecommand > somelogfile.txt &`

Comment: This works . Thank you so much!